# How to get data if exists more than one div with same class on Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

## When page loads, I can find, 1 div, 2 divs, 3 divs or 0 div, on every load

## An example with 3 divs below:

```
<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-1</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-1</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-2</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-3</span>
</div>

<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-2</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-10</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-20</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-30</span>
</div>

<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-3</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-100</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-200</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-300</span>
</div>
```

## My Python code

```
html = webdriver.Firefox()

html.get('DYNAMIC_URL')

html_source = html.page_source

html_source_bs = bs(html_source, 'html.parser')

all_divs = html_source_bs.find_all('div', class_='SOME_DIV')

span_litle = all_divs[0].find('div', class_='class_title')
span_1 = all_divs[0].find_all('span', class_=lambda c: '_some_class1' in c)
span_2 = all_divs[0].find_all('span', class_=lambda c: '_some_class2' in c)
span_3 = all_divs[0].find_all('span', class_=lambda c: '_some_class3' in c)

title_list = ['Title']
span1_list = ['Span1']
span2_list = ['Span2']
span3_list = ['Span3']

for l_title in corrida_numero:
    result = l_title.strip()
    title_list.append(result)
        
for l_1 in participantes_numeros[0:]:
    result = l_1.text.strip()
    span1_list.append(result)

for l_2 in participantes_nomes[0:]:
    result = l_2.text.strip()
    span2_list.append(result)

for l_3 in participantes_odds[0:]:
    result = l_3.text.strip()
    span3_list.append(result)


print(title_list)
print(span1_list)
print(span2_list)
print(span3_list)
```

## Output

```
['Title', 'TITLE-1']
['Span1', 'VALUE-1']
['Span2', 'VALUE-2']
['Span3', 'VALUE-3']
```

## Expected Output if there are 3 divs

```
['Title', 'TITLE-1']
['Span1', 'VALUE-1']
['Span2', 'VALUE-2']
['Span3', 'VALUE-3']

['Title', 'TITLE-2']
['Span1', 'VALUE-10']
['Span2', 'VALUE-20']
['Span3', 'VALUE-30']

['Title', 'TITLE-3']
['Span1', 'VALUE-100']
['Span2', 'VALUE-200']
['Span3', 'VALUE-300']
```

I'm web scraping information from one site. When the site loads, I can find one div with class 'SOME_DIV, 2 divs, or 3 divs, or even more and also any div (0).

If there are 3 divs with class 'SOME_DIV' when webdriver loads the page, then I want to get info for all the divs.

At this moment, I can get only the first div data with "all_divs[0].find_all", I want to get data of other divs if exists, but i don't kwnow how many divs will be find until the page loads.

Comment: _At this moment, I can get only the first div data with "all_divs[0].find_all", I want to get data of other divs if exists, but i don't kwnow how many divs will be find until the page loads._ Then use a loop? Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, why are you using both BeautifulSoup and Selenium? What can BeautifulSoup do that Selenium can't?

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner, I'll read How to Ask and come back to try to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the length of all_divs and use a for loop and the corresponding index to scrape and parse the data.

see sample code below,

```
all_divs = html_source_bs.find_all('div', class_='SOME_DIV')

span_title = []
span_1 =[]
span_2 =[]
span_3 =[]
for i in range(len(all_divs):
    span_title.append(all_divs[i].find('div', class_='class_title'))
    span_1.append(all_divs[0].find_all('span', class_=lambda c: '_some_class1' in c))
    #Add span_2 & 3 here
```

Comment: Why use a loop over the indices, and not the elements themselves?

Comment: @AMC I would have preferred to use elements for loop over, but question does not have much details about web page/url and its details.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-1</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-1</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-2</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-3</span>
</div>

<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-2</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-10</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-20</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-30</span>
</div>

<div class="SOME_dIV">
     <span class="class_title">TITLE-3</span>
     <span class="_some_class1">VALUE-100</span>
     <span class="_some_class2">VALUE-200</span>
     <span class="_some_class3">VALUE-300</span>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.selects('div.SOME_dIV')
titles = divs.select('span.class_title')
for title in titles:
  print (title.text, title.nexts.text)
```

Result:

```
TITLE-1 ['VALUE-1', 'VALUE-2', 'VALUE-3']
TITLE-2 ['VALUE-10', 'VALUE-20', 'VALUE-30']
TITLE-3 ['VALUE-100', 'VALUE-200', 'VALUE-300']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples